# NopCommerce Stripe Configuration

Tags: nopcommerce

I have downloaded the new Stripe payment plugin for nopCommerce 3.40.  I unzipped it and uploaded it to my plugins folder.  I installed it on the admin end.  When I go to configure it I dont get the configure page.  I get the following errors.

Firefox:

[image]

FireBug:

[image]

I had a similar problem not to long ago.  I'm not sure if this is different or if I just cant remember correctly what I did to fix it.

Comment: Can you share the plugin you installed? Mostly looks like route is not registered correctly.